# EPPlus series with default values

Tags: excel, charts, line, epplus

I want to create a chart like as picture. But I don't know how to add red lines to chart. I am using Epplus library. The x value of the first red line is 68 and the y values is 0-100. The second red line is the same, just the x value is 78.

how ı can?

[image]